# Netbeans and CodeIgniter on Windows and Linux?

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans

I installed a plugin for NB 7.0.1 which enabled CodeIgniter but when I went to create a project using it, I was told I need to specify a PHP interpreter for Netbeans. I tried to do this using the php.exe you get with Xampp but I get a `Java null pointer` error. I can't seem to fix this but I'm thinking, why do I need an interpreter on Windows when the Linux machine can do that? I have already set this up on the VM.

Any advice from here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This sounds like a bug in NetBeans. I'd update to the latest version or reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using NB 7.1.1 and had similar issue with CodeIgniter plugin when creating a new project.  NetBeans would complain No PHP Interpreter was defined in Tools->Options->PHP General.  It would not enable finish button so a New Project could not be setup.

I just created a *dummy* batch file called nb_cli.bat and pointed NB to that for the PHP interpreter.  I don't plan on executing (or debugging) CodeIgniter CLI code on local machine so that file will likely never get executed.

If you want to debug or run php locally, make sure xammp works OK outside of NetBeans.  But if not, this fix should get you by the NetBeans issues.

I have a separate linux server on my local network for development as I don't need apache/php locally when I use multiple machines for dev/testing/etc.

NetBeans should bugfix that by downing that PHP Interpreter message from an Alert preventing project setup to a warning that No PHP interpreter is defined (or found) so CLI testing may not function.

As an alternative, if you have a linux box with NB installed, you can create the New project there and copy the whole folder (including the nbproject folder) to your PC and you should be able to get by having No PHP Interpreter defined.

Hopefully that gets you going with NB and CodeIgniter.  If you need additional details, just ask.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I fixed it in the end by uninstalling Netbeans and installing it again.

Comment: glad you got around it.  I think still an issue with NB (requiring PHP interpreter to be specified) as I up'd to NB 7.1.1 on 2 boxes (1 windows, 1 linux) and still had to work around for the windows box, linux fine of course.  Hopefully this helps someone else getting started with NB and CodeIngiter ;-)